# Wooden covering of a well

Tags: joinery, design

I have no experience in woodworking, and only have a rudimentary equipment, but my well needs a new covering, and it would be nice to have some advice.

The parameters (just to have an idea):

- diameter of the well (the actual hole): 95 cm
- height of the brick side of the well: 1 m
- width of the brick side of the well: 30cm

My question is:

How could I join wooden slats together to build a circular covering?

- It should be safe and stable.

I guess it would be a good idea to add some mechanism to prevent the covering slipping away, but this shouldn't be too difficult, and can be done independently.

- The slats shouldn't fit together too firmly, in order to let the well breath a bit - so no gluing.

I appreciate any advice!

UPDATE:

Here is a photo to have a better idea (though this well is larger, so the technique is not necessarily the same I guess):

[image: wooden covering of a well]

Comment: Welcome to woodworking.stackexchange.  A photo would be helpful.

Comment: @Ashlar Hi, I have added a photo.

Comment: Given that this is safety equipment,  I would suggest looking for standard plans known to be strong and weather-resustant rather than inventing a version de novo.

Comment: @Fee-fi-fo-fum I was asking for a photo of your well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How could I join wooden slats together to build a circular covering?

Numerous ways this can be done, including simple butt joints (the straight sides of the boards glued together), pocket screws (with glue or without), screwing or nailing separate boards to boards running at 90° underneath or on top. Last but not least, as in the photo you included, separate boards joined somehow to a framework underneath — much like you'd build the top of an oval farmhouse table.

All of these are more difficult to do properly than you might expect without the right selection of tools or experience in using them.

So instead I'd suggest you buy a quality piece of exterior plywood (e.g. marine-grade). This will make the job infinitely easier and faster for a novice to complete, the cutting to size might even be done for free where you buy the plywood. 12mm plywood would probably be strong enough but 18mm ply is not much more expensive usually and obviously stronger and heavier.

If you would prefer to use solid wood and would like to build something that will last well exposed to weather you should choose softwood that has been treated with preservative (deck boards would be an excellent choice) or a wood that is naturally resistant to rot, which would usually be relatively expensive.

> I guess it would be a good idea to add some mechanism to prevent the covering slipping away, but this shouldn't be too difficult, and can be done independently.

Small blocks of wood glued, nailed or screwed near the edge underneath would be enough for it to 'register' against the inside edge of the hole, while still allowing it to be lifted off and placed into position with ease. Only three blocks would be enough for a good registered fit.

Remember the cover doesn't have to be circular just because the well is, it can be square if you want to save time and effort. If the projecting corners being sharp are a safety concern they can be rounded slightly but there's no reason the cover *has* to match the shape of the well.

> The slats shouldn't fit together too firmly, in order to let the well breath a bit - so no gluing.

I don't think you need to worry about this as the fit of the cover to the top of the brick wall won't even be close to airtight. But if necessary you could drill holes in the board to provide ventilation.